# How to remove unwanted character in php using preg_replace?

Tags: php

im using this code

```
$output = preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F)]*/','', $output);
```

my goal is to remove this character  but the code removed all unwanted characters.

Please help me to remove that character.

Thanks.

Comment: @sachleen thank you. one more thing, how should i put the U+1F60A in code? I really not familiar about the format of preg_replace. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just use `str_replace()`? I hear allot of things about regex being a greedy, inefficient so and so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [this site](http://code.cside.com/3rdpage/us/javaUnicode/converter.html) to find the code for that character. Your code replaces all characters *not* in the range `\x20-\x7F`

I don't know how to do it using that code, but if you just put the character in there, it works. Be careful though, if your text editor doesn't support Unicode it might replace it with nothing so when you save the file, it won't work.

```
echo preg_replace('/*/','', $str);
> ter but th
echo str_replace('', '',  $str);
> ter but th
```

Comment: No, it replaces all characters NOT in \x20-\x7F.  See the ^ after the [.  Your code should not work because you replace everything except the chars you want removed.

Comment: @sachleen i got this error
Warning: preg_replace() Compilation failed: PCRE does not support \L, \l, \N{name}, \U, or \u